# The code seems to have a logic error but when I run it works the way I would like

Tags: c, logic

I tried to make a celsius to Fahrenheit and Kelvin converter but there seems to be a logical error in the part where the program asks for user input about what kind of conversion to do.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define Fx 1.8
#define Fy 32
#define Kx 273.15
int main(){
    double c;
    double f;
    int choice;
    printf("Convert Celsius to:\n[1] Fahrenheit\n[2] Kelvin\n");
    do{
        printf("Choose: ");
        scanf("%i", &choice);
    }while(choice != 1 && choice != 2); 
    if (choice == 1){
        printf("°C = ");
        scanf("%lf", &c);
        f = c * Fx + Fy;
        printf("°F = %f\n", f);
    }
    else{
        printf("°C = ");
        scanf("%lf", &c);
        printf("°K = %lf\n", c + Kx);
    }

   
    return 0;
}
```

In the part `while(choice != 1 && choice != 2);` should have a logical error. The operator checks if choice is different from 1 and different from 2. If the user input was 1 the operator should be false and true and rerun the query, but it executes normally. There should be a problem and run the same question over and over but it doesn't. When I use the boolean operator `||` that the repetition of the question happens.I want to know what's going on here.

Comment: Not the way AND works.

Comment: So... ? The loop is executing when the condition is true. When input is `1`, it is false as you said.

Comment: Let's say, "We'll do this if Luiz is not an elephant AND if Luiz is not a giraffe."  Now, you're not an elephant and you're not a giraffe, so we don't do the thing.

Comment: But now change things up: "We'll do this if Luiz is not a human AND if Luiz is not a giraffe."  Now, you're not a giraffe, but you ARE a human, so we'll do the thing.

Comment: so only one of the conditions needs to be true?

Comment: AND means, both conditions need to be true.  But: "Luiz is not a human" is not true.  Similarly, `choice != 1` is not true.

Comment: Now I get it, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The part `while(choice != 1 && choice != 2);` doesn't have logic error.

When `1` is entered, `choice != 1` is false, so the condition is false and the loop ends.

When `2` is entered, `choice != 1` is true, but `choice != 2` is false, so the condition is also false and the loop ends.

When `3` is entered, both of `choice != 1` and `choice != 2` are true, so the condition is true and the loop continues.

However, your code has a problem: You didn't check the return value of `scanf()`. For example, when `3` is entered at first and then `a` is entered, `a` is not a valid input for `%i` and it is not consumed. `choice` remains `3` and the loop goes infinitely.

Comment: I tested it by giving an A input and it actually keeps running infinitely. Thank you for the warning.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is for `choice` to be `1` or `2`.  So, you will be good if

```
(choice == 1) || (choice == 2)
```

This means that you want to go into the loop if its negation is true, or

```
!((choice == 1) || (choice == 2))
```

Just apply De Morgan's Law and you get

```
( !(choice == 1) && !(choice == 2) )
```

or

```
((choice != 1) && (choice != 2))
```

Which shows that what you have is not an error.